# Access claims in web api controller in mvc5 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, claims

I have a MVC5 project with ASP.NET Identity. I'm using Claims in my MVC5 controllers like below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var  prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var email = prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

However the Claims are not available in a WebApi controller in the same project. What do I have to do to get access to the Claims of the logged in user in a WebApi Controller in a MVC5 project?

Thank You.

Comment: You need to have `[Authorize]` attribute decorated on top of your WebAPI controller or actions to access claims.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your WebAPI controller or action is decorated with `[Authorize]`. You will never get current user context for anonymous requests.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {

        try
        {
            var user = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal; //OR
            var prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            var email = prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return InternalServerError(ex);

        }
        return Ok();
   }
```